# Cost of empty inline function?

Tags: swift, function, debugging, inline

I'm writing a debugging function that will be called from other function in my project. This function is marked as `@inline(__always)`, and does nothing if `DEBUG` is `0`.

Does this function have any cost whatsoever at `DEBUG == 0`? I'm pretty sure that the answer is no, but I just want to confirm it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could compare the disassembly of the source file to check?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Zero cost

---

## Elaboration

I'm assuming your function looks something like this:

```swift
@inline(__always)
func myFunction() {
    #if DEBUG
    doStuff()
    doStuff()
    doStuff()
    #endif
}
```

First, the preprocessor directives are followed. So if your `DEBUG` flag is `0`, you can think of it as being preprocessed into this:

```swift
@inline(__always)
func myFunction() {
}
```

When you call `myFunction` anywhere, it's replaced with its contents at compile time. Assuming `DEBUG` is still `0`, can think of it like this:

```swift
// What you wrote:
func myOtherFunction() {
    print("Before")
    myFunction()
    print("After")
}

// Imagine it becoming this while compiling:
func myOtherFunction() {
    print("Before")
    print("After")
}
```

And, as you can see, the non-content of your inlined empty function are included, introducing zero cost to calling this function in this compilation environment.

<sub>Obviously, Swift code is not compiled into more Swift code. That's why I said you can imagine this; it's not truly what's happening. In actuality, it gets compiled into [LLVM IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM#Intermediate_representation), but the end result is the same.</sub>